# Large file dask groupby and apply

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory, dask

I'm dealing with a relatively "large" dataset (csv, ~16M of unique id's,8 features etc..).

```
db_dual = './file.csv', blocksize='64MB' ,sep=',',decimal=".", low_memory=True, usecols=include, dtype={"id": "string","cc": "string","pd": "string","cs": "string","coms": "string","cap": "string","in": "string",'ncn': "string","coms": "string"})
```

I want to group by the data set and apply this function for each group

```
def vDual(df):

    # FD
    if len(df) == 1 and (df['cc'].eq('DUAL')).any():
      df['FD'] = 1


    # VD
    if len(df) == 2 and (df['cs'].eq('E')).any() and (df['cs'].eq('G')).any():
      df['VD'] = 1
    return df
```

In dask I'm using:

```
db_dual = db_dual.groupby(['cf','coms','cap','in','ncn']).apply(vDual, meta={'FD': 'int', 'VD': 'int'})
db_dual.compute()
```

The problem is that the command is consuming a lot of ram with conseguent saturation and crash of the script.

[image: Ram Saturation]

I'm running the script in a Google Colab

any idea? What am I doing wrong?

I

Input Data

[image]

Expected Output:

[image]

PS) The approach works perfectly with a subset of data, but it does not scale with the full dataset.

Thanks

Comment: Please add a sample of your data and expected output

Comment: db_dual.compute() will probably load your entire input dataset into memory since your not reducing its dimension. How big is it?